# Running makefile command as another user

Tags: linux, makefile

I have two scripts, owned by root.

```
#!/bin/sh
#script1.sh
echo "all: first" > my_makefile
echo >> my_makefile
echo "first: " >> my_makefile
echo "\ttouch file.txt" >> my_makefile

#!/bin/sh
#script2.sh
while true
do
 make -f my_makefile
 sleep 10
done
```

script2.sh is called as "sudo sh script.sh" and continually runs make on my_makefile. script1.sh is called by individual users to alter the makefile.

How can I run the makefile command so that the file.txt is owned by the user, rather than root?

Comment: "...owned by the user..." You mean the last user who ran `script1.sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I wasn't using sudo correctly. I just needed to replace the last line of script2.sh with:

```
echo "sudo su -m -l `whoami` -c \"touch file.txt\"" >> my_makefile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
#script1.sh
...
echo "\tchown "`logname`" file.txt" >> my_makefile
```

Comment: Maybe my example was too simple. I need to handle the case where many files of undertermined names are produced by a command in the makefile.